# KeyError when using custom aggregration with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to use `pandas` to perform multiple aggregations (some custom), but I'm getting `KeyError: 'type'` when I use the `agg`. I thought that I'm writing my own aggregation correctly, but apparently not.  How can I change my own aggregrations `count_tweets()` and `count_retweets()` to correctly provide a count of tweets and retweets as columns in the new dataframe.

```
# create example data
df = pd.DataFrame([['user1', 'tweet', 400],
                   ['user1', 'retweet', 405],
                   ['user2', 'tweet', 10],
                   ['user2', 'tweet', 10],
                   ['user1', 'tweet', 450],
                   ['user3', 'retweet', 8],
                   ['user1', 'tweet', 500]],
                  columns=['user', 'type', 'followers'])

# group by user
grouped = df.groupby('user')

# create custom aggregration to count tweets
def count_tweets(arr):
    return len(arr[arr['type'] == 'tweet'])

# create custom aggregration to count retweets
def count_retweets(arr):
    return len(arr[arr['type'] == 'retweet'])

# define aggregrations
args = {'followers': 'mean',
        'type': 'count',
        'type': [count_tweets, count_retweets]}

# apply aggregrations to grouped data
results = grouped.agg(args)

KeyError: 'type'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `agg` it's going to use those functions on series objects.  Therefore, when you specify that `count_tweets` should run over column `type` there is no reason to try and grab the type column again within the function.

```
def count_tweets(arr):
    return len(arr[arr == 'tweet'])

def count_retweets(arr):
    return len(arr[arr == 'retweet'])

# define aggregrations
args = {
    'followers': 'mean',
    'type': ['count', count_tweets, count_retweets]
}

df.groupby('user').agg(args)

      followers  type                            
           mean count count_tweets count_retweets
user                                             
user1    438.75     4            3              1
user2     10.00     2            2              0
user3      8.00     1            0              1
```

---

That said, I don't like how you've done this.  By all means, use my corrections of you code.  However, if you are interested, I prefer these approaches.

**Option 1**
You can use the `groupby` `pipe` method to pipeline this.  I'll combine an `agg` to handle `mean` and `count` and use `value_counts` to handle counting types of types.

```
df.groupby('user').pipe(
    lambda g: g.agg(dict(followers='mean', type='count'))
               .join(g.type.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0))
)

       followers  type  retweet  tweet
user                                  
user1     438.75     4        1      3
user2      10.00     2        0      2
user3       8.00     1        1      0
```

---

**Option 2**
Use `pd.get_dummies` prior to a `groupby`

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.type)).groupby('user').agg(
    dict(followers='mean', type='count', retweet='sum', tweet='sum')
)

       followers  type  retweet  tweet
user                                  
user1     438.75     4        1      3
user2      10.00     2        0      2
user3       8.00     1        1      0
```